# dojo.cookie delete completely

Tags: cookies, browser, dojo

I set up dojo.cookie("foo"), and it is called on several other pages. Then I set to delete the cookie with 'dojo.cookie("foo", null, {expire: -1})' whenever a certain page say, fooClear.html, is loaded. I noticed that dojo.cookie("list") is deleted only for fooClear.html; if I call dojo.cookie("foo") on the other pages, it still contains the old data unless I close the browser.

I believe this is a cache issue. But how do I delete a cookie completely in dojo? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

To delete all cookies on current page (path);

```
var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
  name = cookies[i].split("=")[0];
  document.cookie = name + "=; expires=" + +new Date;
}
```

In your case, i would suggest changing path to '/' so that any cookies are exposed, everywhere on your page, be it under samples '/basket/list.html', '/epay/submit/basket.html' etc.

What has happened in your previous cookie assignments is, that you've left out the path property while setting cookies - this results in said cookie under the document.cookie 'inherits' the document.location from where it was set. E.g. when under '/admin/save.html' and calling *dojo.cookie* as *set* it would default to dojo.cookie("foo", "value", {path:'/admin/'})

There's no way of purging *all* cookies under a domain - if you do no know the path in which it was set. So, if the above for loop was executed under '/', then any '/admin/' path'ed cookies still remain - because theyre not exposed to the '/' path

Comment: Hi mschr, after playing with the code, I now better understand how cookie works and what you meant. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

By design, cookies are saved first pr-domain then pr-path. This means that if you assign a cookie to a mydomain.tld/rootpath/ path, then all subsequent paths are using the same cookie.

What you need to do, is when the cookie is created, pass a parameter to the configuration, 'path', for instance:

In **mydomain.tld/foo.html** when cookie is set in a js block, use:

```
dojo.cookie("mCookie", "contents", {path: '/', domain:'mydomain.tld'})
// domain is the default, can be omitted
```

Comment: Hi mschr, thank you for being so responsive! I really appreciate it. I am a bit confused, though. You said above that "if you assign a cookie to a mydomain.tld/rootpath/ path, then all subsequent paths are using the same cookie.". Do you mean that if I set a cookie on mydomain.tld/rootpath/, it does not work on mydomain.tld/rootpath/path; but if I set it on mydomain.tld/rootpath/path, it will work on mydomain.tld/rootpath/, just like what's said in comment: 1 at http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/8038? If so, then it's odd because this is not what I have seen in the case I have...

Comment: no, not sure i get you correct but i think youre usecase is the 'other way around'.. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Domain_and_Path. Lets say you from /index.html do `cookie("root_cook", "value", { path:'/' });` then rest of calls to index.html will send/contain cookie - and also /other.html contains cookie. Here's what i meant; ALSO /subfolder/index.html contains cookie 'root_cook' since its a subfolder of the path '/', digg?

Comment: The link is very helpful. Thank you! It's just that my situation is actually a bit complicated. I set up a cookie for the dnd dropped items so that they can be used on different pages. The items are added to the cookie from every page whenever there is a drop event. My code works very well in terms of retrieving the cookie (even though I do not include the argument, path: '/'). The problem I have is that I don't know how to delete the cookie completely. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working, but I suspect it is because of the way I set up the URL's (paths). I will fix that and try your suggestion. Thank you!